Is it kufr to lie about being Muslim out of fear?
My parents don’t really like Islam that much and I’ve tried to tell them that I am Muslim, but they simply don’t understand and when I give them reasons why I am a Muslim. They shrug it off and it seems like they really want me out of Islam and so out of the fear That both they won’t accept me and that they will spread wiswas into my head, causing kufr, I lie to them. is this kufr please respond quickly. If I did commit kufr Do I need to retake my shahada?
